# Visual Studio ASP.NET aspx page empty lines bug

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I am creating an ASP.NET app in Visual Studio 2013 which has about 12 pages. However, in one of the page's aspx page in VS, when I save or auto format the page it will insert/create hundreds of empty lines. Most recently it has managed to create over 300,000 lines.

[image]

I keep deleting these lines, which is quite time consuming because the lines are spread throughout the code, but they just keep getting inserted.

This bug does not occur on any other page, the only thing that is different about this page is that it uses a DevExpress ASPxPageControl, but I'm not sure how that would have anything to do with it.

I have tried deleting the page and copying the code over to a new page, but the same bug keeps occuring. Does anybody have any idea how I would go about fixing this bug?

UPDATE: I have created another page which also uses the DevExpress ASPxPageControl and it has started to happen on this as well. So I am assuming that this issue has to do with the control.

UPDATE 19/09: This issue no longer happens, but I have no idea why or how it has been fixed.

UPDATE 06/12: The issue appears to happen only when design view is opened. If I only ever look at the source view, it never happens.

Comment: I don't know about the bug, but you can replace empty lines pressing "Ctrl + H" on your keyboard. [Here's](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-remove-blank-lines-in-visual-studio1) the regex. It should, at least, save you some time.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi Thanks, this will definitely save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77957/visual-studio-keeps-adding-blank-lines) that looks like the same problem you have.

Try checking if you are missing any closing tags.